# Get PostGIS geometry field on Drill

Tags: postgresql, postgis, apache-drill

I have a table with a geometry column and if I query it using PostGIS, it shows the records right:

PostGIS query image:

[image: PostGIS query image]

The problem is when I execute the query using Apache Drill, because it shows all the records fine except the geometry one, it shows as null.

Drill query image:

[image: Drill query image]

Reviewing the logs, it shows the following error:

> WARN o.a.d.e.store.jdbc.JdbcRecordReader - Ignoring column that is
>   unsupported. org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserException:
>
> UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION ERROR: A column you queried has a data type that
>   is not currently supported by the JDBC storage plugin. The column's
>   name was geom_multipolygon and its JDBC data type was OTHER

I tested creating the Drill storage plugin with **postgis-jdbc-2.2.1.jar** and **postgresql-42.1.4.jar** but the same error is shown.

If I use:

```
cast(geom_multipolygon as varchar(255))
```

it shows the varchar representation of the geometry, another option is getting the MULTIPOLYGON text and transform to Drill binary using `ST_GeomFromText(geom)`, but we need the binary format directly from PostGIS, so those approaches can't be done.

We have seen this page: https://github.com/k255/drill-gis/issues/1 but the proposed solution doesn't work for us, so I think there is a way to achieve this.

**UPDATE:** I finally found the way that Drill can show the geo fields, is to change the data type in PostGIS from *geometry* to *bytea*. It seems to be a compatibility issue. With this way, we can perform geospatial queries on Drill, but in PostGIS those fields are no longer geometries, so they can not be indexed and treated as such.